# Understanding why I cannot reference this.property in Javascript "Class"

Tags: javascript, closures, html5-video

I have the following Protoype for an interactive Video Player class...

```
// default constructor
function BrightPlayer() { };

    // prototypes for basic properties
    BrightPlayer.prototype.CurrentCourse = null;
    BrightPlayer.prototype.CurrentTopic = null;
    BrightPlayer.prototype.CurrentSubTopic = null;
    BrightPlayer.prototype.CurrentTimestamp = null;
    BrightPlayer.prototype.VideoSelector = null;
    BrightPlayer.prototype.VideoObject = null;

    BrightPlayer.prototype.Heartbeat = function () {
        setInterval(this.ApplicationPulse, 1000);
    };

    BrightPlayer.prototype.ApplicationPulse = function () {
        // javascript errors occurs on the next line.
        // VideoObject is undefined.
        this.CurrentTimestamp = this.VideoObject.currentTime;
        console.log('pulse....');
    };

    BrightPlayer.prototype.Init = function () {
        // My thoughts were that the following line would initialize
        // the VideoObject in this instance, and subsequent calls
        // in the Application Pulse would have this reference, but it's not working
        this.VideoObject = document.getElementById("brightplayer-video");
        this.Heartbeat();
    };
```

The class is instantiated and Init is launched from my main HTML page.

```
<script>
    var Aplayer = new BrightPlayer();
    Aplayer.Init();
</script>
```

However, if I add   this.VideoObject = document.getElementById("brightplayer-video"); inside of the ApplicationPulse function, it works.

I.E.

```
BrightPlayer.prototype.ApplicationPulse = function () {
            this.VideoObject = document.getElementById("brightplayer-video");
            this.CurrentTimestamp = this.VideoObject.currentTime;
            console.log('pulse....');
        };
```

This is sloppy though, i don't want to have to do the element lookup on every pulse.  I must be missing something when trying to relate Javascript classes to C# classes.  Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use jQuery and you can get the video player with $('#brightplayer-video').  jQuery is pretty efficient and I don't think you will see any slowdown in your webpage in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming because of using `this`.

`setInterval` is defined as a Function of the browser `window` object. The context of `this` when called from `setInterval` is different i.e. is `window`.  So everything gets assigned on `window`. The property `window.VideoObject` doesn't exist and hence your code doesn't work.

`this` in javascript works differently than in C#. In javascript, `this` is bound by **how the function is called** (ignoring Arrow functions). So, in your case, the function is called from the `window` object.

So, to solve your problem you need to bind the `this` correctly. There are different ways.

1. Storing a reference to this function in another variable `self = this;`
2. Using `bind` function . `setInterval(this.ApplicationPulse.bind(this), 1000))`

Comment: This fixed it.  Thanks for introducing me to .bind! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
BrightPlayer.prototype.Heartbeat = function () {
    setInterval(this.ApplicationPulse, 1000);
};
```

When you pass `this.ApplicationPulse` to `setInterval`, it gets called with a different context. You want to explicitly define the context in which `ApplicationPulse` will run by binding it to `this`:

```
BrightPlayer.prototype.Heartbeat = function () {
    setInterval(this.ApplicationPulse.bind(this), 1000);
};
```

Comment: You were correct, it's just that Agalo beat you by 1 minute, otherwise I would have marked you correct.  Thanks so much for introducing me to .bind :)